# Display a users last login date on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a beginner and I'm looking for a way to display the date of the latest login of a specific user (user 2 in this case) on my Wordpress site as a simple row of text like this:

> User last login: 2015-01-18

I have struggled with this code below but I can't get it to work (put it in my funcions.php).

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ){
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
```

And this where I want the date to display:

```
get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', true );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a good start, next part is where do you want to show it? Try printing that value in one of your template files.

Comment: As James said, it's a good start! What exactly is your problem? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I want it to show on my front page. The _function_ code is pasted in to the themes funcions.php. The _get_user_ code I'm planning to add in a plugin called "PHP Code Snippets" that implements php into a specific place in any page. (This plugin served me well in another thing I was doing, so it should work fine). When I'm doing this the line don't show up. So this is where I'm stuck. So I suspected that it might be something wring with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that this returns as an array - if you print it out, you'll see it's an array with a timestamp inside. You could do something like this:

```
$userMeta = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_last_login', false );
$lastLogin = $userMeta[0];
echo date('d m Y', $lastLogin);
```

Which should spit out a date in whatever format you want.